# Slice and assign in a pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

At first we create a small `pd.DataFrame` with MultiIndex on both axis:

```
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 1), ('b', 3)], names=['col_1', 'col_2'])
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(pd.Timestamp('2023-03-01'), 'A'), (pd.Timestamp('2023-03-01'), 'B'), (pd.Timestamp('2023-03-01'), 'C'), (pd.Timestamp('2023-03-02'), 'A'), (pd.Timestamp('2023-03-02'), 'B'), (pd.Timestamp('2023-03-03'), 'B'), (pd.Timestamp('2023-03-03'), 'C')], names=['idx_1', 'idx_2'])
data = np.arange(len(index) * len(columns)).reshape(len(index), len(columns))
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns, data=data)
```

So we get

```
col_1              a       b    
col_2              2   3   1   3
idx_1      idx_2                
2023-03-01 A       0   1   2   3
           B       4   5   6   7
           C       8   9  10  11
2023-03-02 A      12  13  14  15
           B      16  17  18  19
2023-03-03 B      20  21  22  23
           C      24  25  26  27
```

Now I want the 'A' and the 'B' rows to be equal:

```
col_1              a       b    
col_2              2   3   1   3
idx_1      idx_2                
2023-03-01 A       4   5   6   7
           B       4   5   6   7
           C       8   9  10  11
2023-03-02 A      16  17  18  19
           B      16  17  18  19
2023-03-03 B      20  21  22  23
           C      24  25  26  27
```

I can do it likes this:

```
df = df.unstack()
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 'A']] = df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 'B']].values
df = df.stack().reindex(index)
```

I wonder if there is another approach without de facto copying the data twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly assign your values, force alignment using [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:, 'A'], :] = df.loc[idx[:, 'B'], :].rename({'B': 'A'}, level='idx_2')
```

Output:

```
col_1              a       b    
col_2              2   3   1   3
idx_1      idx_2                
2023-03-01 A       4   5   6   7
           B       4   5   6   7
           C       8   9  10  11
2023-03-02 A      16  17  18  19
           B      16  17  18  19
2023-03-03 B      20  21  22  23
           C      24  25  26  27
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you had all combinations of levels in order (not the case here!), you could also convert to numpy array

Answer (score 1):

You can assign slices by [`DataFrame.rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) second level of MultiIndex:

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'A'],:] = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'B'],:].rename({'B':'A'}, level=1)

print (df)
col_1              a       b    
col_2              2   3   1   3
idx_1      idx_2                
2023-03-01 A       4   5   6   7
           B       4   5   6   7
           C       8   9  10  11
2023-03-02 A      16  17  18  19
           B      16  17  18  19
2023-03-03 B      20  21  22  23
           C      24  25  26  27
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd1=dd.reset_index()
    dd1.loc[dd1.idx_2=='A',[ ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 1), ('b', 3)]]=dd1.loc[dd1.idx_2=='B',[ ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 1), ('b', 3)]].values
    return dd1.set_index(['idx_1', 'idx_2'])

df.groupby(level=0).apply(function1)
```

out:

```
col_1              a       b    
col_2              2   3   1   3
idx_1      idx_2                
2023-03-01 A       4   5   6   7
           B       4   5   6   7
           C       8   9  10  11
2023-03-02 A      16  17  18  19
           B      16  17  18  19
2023-03-03 B      20  21  22  23
           C      24  25  26  27
```